# How to make my Shiny app modules communicate

Tags: r, shiny

I have the following set-up in my app:

- UI module displaying a sidebarPanel. The corresponding server function initiates some calculations in the backend and returns the output in the form of a list of (almost) arbitrarily many data frames.
- table module displaying the output received from UI module.
- plot module displaying the output received from UI module.

The issue I am facing is that I am unsure how I can allow both my `tabs` to modify the object `val` and to kick off the corresponding events in my modules. Furthermore and similarly, I do not have a clear understanding of how I can make my `userInputPanels` with one another such that they stay identical when the tab is switched.

I have collected here a MWE illustrating my situation:

**ui_module.R**

```
# Contrary to its name, this module is also responsible for executing the 
# backend logic when the submit button is pressed
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
library(shiny)


inputPanel <- function(id, i18n) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  sidebarPanel(
    # in reality here we have A LOT more elements
    actionButton(
      inputId = ns("submit"),
      label = "Submit"
    )
  )
}


inputServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      
      # Writing important data into session$userData
      session$userData$submit <- reactive(input$submit)
      
      observe({
        # when data in one user interface changes, the other should update so 
        # that they stay consistent! Thus I need to make the two objects 
        # communicate with one another, but I have not been able to make this
        # work.
      })
      
      val <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
      observe({
        # In reality, this calls a backend function computing a list of data.frames
        val$data <- lapply(1:sample(1:10, 1), function(i) {
          data.frame(X=rnorm(10), Y=rnorm(10))
        })
      }) %>% bindEvent(input$submit)
      
      return(val)
    }
  )
}
```

**table_module.R**

```
library(shiny)


tableTabPanel <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabPanel(
    title="Tables",
    sidebarLayout(
      # From what I understand, this is how I have to utilize modules when I call them from inside other modules so that session$ns gives me the proper id on the server side of things
      inputPanel(paste(id, "navPanel", sep="-")),
      mainPanel(
        uiOutput(ns("tabsetPanel"))
      )
    )
  )
}


tableServer <- function(id, val_outer=NULL) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    # I tried doing something like this, but clearly it is not working
    # val_inner <- inputServer("navPanel", i18n_r)
    # observe({
    #   val_outer <- val_inner
    # }) %>% bindEvent(val_inner)
    
    # this way, without the inter-communicability it works:
    val <- inputServer("navPanel")
    
    ns <- session$ns
    observe({
      # I am having a hard time creating a MWE. Please understand that I 
      # have tried quite hard to make this minimal example work, but for some 
      # reason, the tables are not rendered. Still, I assume that the 
      # idea and the root of my problem shall be clear to observers since it 
      # is not related to actually rendering any tables
      
      # !is.null to avoid error on startup when val_outer is empty
      if (!is.null(val$data)) {
        lapply(seq_along(val$data), function(i) {
            output[[paste0("table", i)]] <- renderTable(val$data[[i]])
        })
      }
    }) %>% bindEvent(val)
    
    output$tabsetPanel <- renderUI({
      browser()
      tabPanels <-
        if (!is.null(val$data)) {
          lapply(
            X = seq_along(val$data),
            FUN = function(i) {
              tabPanel(title = paste("Tab", i),
                       tableOutput(ns(paste0("table", i))))
            }
          )
        } else {
          list(NULL)
        }
      
      do.call(tabsetPanel, tabPanels)
    })
    
    return(val)
  })
}
```

**plot_module.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)


plotTabPanel <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabPanel(
    title="Plots",
    sidebarLayout(
      inputPanel(paste(id, "navPanel", sep="-")),
      mainPanel(
        uiOutput(ns("tabsetPanel"))
      )
    )
  )
}


plotServer <- function(id, val_outer) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    # I tried doing something like this, but clearly it is not working
    val_inner <- inputServer("navPanel", i18n_r)
    observe({
      val_outer <- val_inner
    }) %>% bindEvent(val_inner)
    
    
    ns <- session$ns
    observe({
      # !is.null to avoid error on startup when val_outer is empty
      if (!is.null(val_outer$data)) {
        lapply(seq_along(val_outer$data), function(i) {
          output[[paste0("table", i)]] <-
            renderPlot(ggplot(data=val$data[[i]]) + geom_point(x=X, y=Y))
        })
      }
    })

    output$tabsetPanel <- renderUI({
      tabList <-   
        if (!is.null(val_outer$data)) {
          lapply(seq_along(val_outer$data), function(i) { 
            tabPanel(title = paste("Tab", i),
                     tableOutput(ns(paste0("table", i))))
          })
        } else {
          tabPanel(title = "Sample title")
        }
      
      do.call(tabsetPanel, tabList)
    })

    return(val_outer)
  })
}
```

**main.R**

```
library(shiny)


# some reactiveValues containing various fields
val <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)  # and some more values


ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "title",
  
  tableTabPanel("tableTab"),
  # plotTabPanel("plotTab")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # The idea is to allow the user to access the input panel from both tabs. For this I need to observe, throughout the "lifecycle" of my app, whether changes to val have occured
  val <- tableServer("tableTab", val)
  # val <- plotServer("plotTab", val)
}


shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you call the modules from the main app, it works fine.  Try this

```
library(shiny)

inputPanel <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  sidebarPanel(
    # in reality here we have A LOT more elements
    actionButton(
      inputId = ns("submit"),
      label = "Submit"
    )
  )
}

inputServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns
      
      # Writing important data into session$userData
      session$userData$submit <- reactive(input$submit)
      
      observe({
        # print(input$submit)
        # when data in one user interface changes, the other should update so 
        # that they stay consistent! Thus I need to make the two objects 
        # communicate with one another, but I have not been able to make this
        # work.
      })
      
      val <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)
      observe({
        # In reality, this calls a backend function computing a list of data.frames
        val$data <- lapply(1:sample(1:10, 1), function(i) {
          data.frame(X=rnorm(10), Y=rnorm(10))
        })
        # print(val$data)
      }) %>% bindEvent(input$submit)
      
      return(val)
    }
  )
}

tableTabPanel <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("tabsetPanel"))  
  # tabPanel(
  #   title="Tables",
  #   sidebarLayout(
  #     # From what I understand, this is how I have to utilize modules when I call them from inside other modules so that session$ns gives me the proper id on the server side of things
  #     # inputPanel(paste(id, "navPanel", sep="-")),
  #     inputPanel("navPanel"),
  #     mainPanel(
  #       uiOutput(ns("tabsetPanel"))
  #     )
  #   )
  # )
}


tableServer <- function(id, val) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    # this way, without the inter-communicability it works:
    # val <- inputServer("navPanel")
    
    ns <- session$ns
    observe({
      # I am having a hard time creating a MWE. Please understand that I 
      # have tried quite hard to make this minimal example work, but for some 
      # reason, the tables are not rendered. Still, I assume that the 
      # idea and the root of my problem shall be clear to observers since it 
      # is not related to actually rendering any tables
      
      # !is.null to avoid error on startup when val_outer is empty
      if (!is.null(val$data)) {
        lapply(seq_along(val$data), function(i) {
          output[[paste0("table", i)]] <- renderTable(val$data[[i]])
        })
      } else {print("Hello")}
    }) # %>% bindEvent(val)
    
    output$tabsetPanel <- renderUI({
      # browser()
      tabPanels <-
        if (!is.null(val$data)) {
          lapply(
            seq_along(val$data),
            function(i) {
              tabPanel(title = paste("Tab", i),
                       tableOutput(ns(paste0("table", i))))
            }
          )
        } else {
          list(NULL)
        }
      tagList(
        do.call(tabsetPanel, tabPanels)
      )
      
    })
    
    # return(val)
  })
}

library(ggplot2)

plotTabPanel <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  uiOutput(ns("tabsetPanelp"))
  # tabPanel(
  #   title="Plots",
  #   sidebarLayout(
  #     inputPanel(paste(id, "navPanel", sep="-")),
  #     mainPanel(
  #       uiOutput(ns("tabsetPanelp"))
  #     )
  #   )
  # )
}


plotServer <- function(id, val_outer) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
    ns <- session$ns
    observe({
      # !is.null to avoid error on startup when val_outer is empty
      if (!is.null(val_outer$data)) {
        lapply(seq_along(val_outer$data), function(i) {
          output[[paste0("plot", i)]] <-
            renderPlot({ggplot(data=val_outer$data[[i]], aes(x=X, y=Y)) + geom_point()})
        })
      } else {
        print("Hello P")
        Sys.sleep(1)
      }
    })
    
    output$tabsetPanelp <- renderUI({
      tabList <-   
        if (!is.null(val_outer$data)) {
          lapply(seq_along(val_outer$data), function(i) { 
            tabPanel(title = paste("Tab", i),
                     plotOutput(ns(paste0("plot", i))))
          })
         
        } else {
          list(NULL)
          #tabPanel(title = "Sample title")
        }
      tagList(
        do.call(tabsetPanel, tabList)
      )
    })
    
    return(val_outer)
  })
}

# some reactiveValues containing various fields
# val <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)  # and some more values


ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "title",
  
  tabPanel(
    title="Tables and Plots",
    sidebarLayout(
      inputPanel("navPanel"),
      mainPanel(
        tableTabPanel("tableTab")
        ,plotTabPanel("plotTab")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  val <- inputServer("navPanel")
  # The idea is to allow the user to access the input panel from both tabs. For this I need to observe, throughout the "lifecycle" of my app, whether changes to val have occured
  tableServer("tableTab", val)
  plotServer("plotTab", val)
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```